# Re-order the sequence of facet by the count of attribute

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2

I want to re-order the sequence of facets by the sum of 2016's count. Is there any way to make it?

The following is my original code:

```
library(ggplot2)
Dincident <-read.table("C:/Users/lionel.lee/Documents/Dincident.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
head(Dincident)
d <- Dincident
d_bg <- d[, -4]  
ggplot(d,aes(Month,fill=PDline)) +
  geom_bar(data=d_bg,fill="gray") +
  geom_bar()+
  facet_grid(Year~PDline)+  
  scale_y_continuous(limit = c(0, 8),breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limit = c(0, 12),breaks=c(3,6,9,12))
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: take a look at the `?reorder` function to reorder the factor levels according to some function of another variable ...

Comment: You really need to provide reproducible data, specially when your ordering variable isn't even included in the variables in your code! but as @Ben suggested, take a look at ``reorder``

Answer (score 0):

You can create artificial `ord` column which will indicate sorted total counts depends on `Year` and `PDline`, e.g. `1` - means maximum counts for a given `Year`. Then you will be able to use facetting for `Year` and `ord`. Please see the code below:

```
library(ggplot2)

# data.simulation
set.seed(123)
n <- 200
Dincident <- data.frame(
  Month = sample(1:12, n, replace = TRUE),
  Year = sample(2015:2016, n, replace = TRUE),
  PDline = sample(LETTERS[1:3], n , replace = TRUE),
  Misc = 1:n
)
d <- Dincident
d_bg <- d[, - 4]
x <- as.data.frame(table(Dincident$Year, d$PDline))
x1 <- lapply(
  X = split(x, x$Var1), 
  function(l) {
    l$y <- interaction(l$Var1, l$Var2)
    l <- l[order(l$Freq, decreasing = TRUE), ]
    l$ord <- 1:nrow(l)
    l
  }
)

x2 <- do.call(rbind, x1)
colnames(x2)[1:2] <- c("Year", "PDline")

d <- merge(d, x2)
# data plotting
ggplot(d, aes(Month, fill = PDline)) +
  geom_bar(data = d_bg, fill = "gray") +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(Year ~ ord, labeller = label_context)+  
  scale_y_continuous(limit = c(0, 8), breaks = 1:8) +
  scale_x_continuous(limit = c(0, 12), breaks = (1:4) * 3)   
x2
```

Output (qty of counts per `Year` and `PDline`:

```
       Year PDline Freq      y ord
2015.5 2015      C   43 2015.C   1
2015.1 2015      A   35 2015.A   2
2015.3 2015      B   30 2015.B   3
2016.4 2016      B   33 2016.B   1
2016.2 2016      A   32 2016.A   2
2016.6 2016      C   27 2016.C   3
```

Graph:

[image: graph]